# Using Crm Claims Token when calling a Web API service from a Web Resource

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dynamics-crm-2013, claims-based-identity, adfs, identityserver3

I'm new to Claims Authentication in Crm, and I'm trying to Call a Web API rest service from a Web Resource in Crm using a JQuery Ajax call.  The flow of what I'm trying to do is:

1. Log into Crm using STS.
2. A Dashboard with an html Web Resource is loaded, Ajax Call to Web API Service is made (with Credentials and cross domain).
3. Web API Service uses the Crm Auth tokens to Authenticate.
4. Web API Service Runs and Returns a JSON object.

I've looked into using IdentityServer3 to generate a JWT token, but haven't had much luck.  Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is it tagged "adfs"?

Comment: CRM would have to trust tokens for IdentityServer for that to work. Does CRM allow you to configure the trust? I doubt that it does.

Comment: This Web API service you're talking about...is it a third party endpoint or CRM's Web API endpoint?

Comment: The Web API service is a third party endpoint that I'm developing.  It is being hosted outside of CRM.

Comment: If you develop a Web API then you need your own token service to protect it. If you want SSO across CRM and your token service, then they both need to trust the same Idp.

Comment: @BrockAllen Thanks for the valuable feedback.  I'm still working on validating, but it appears that the issue I'm seeing is related to Crm and adfs being on the same domain as suggested by this post:

http://crmtipoftheday.com/2015/12/23/avoid-using-the-same-domain-for-adfs-and-crm/